# can many users on 1 wifi network cause issues with websockets?

Tags: networking, wifi, websocket

We have a product that allows a group of people watching a presentation to vote on questions in the presentation on their mobile.

The new version of the website that people use to vote uses websockets, for example to get notifications if a vote has opened.

The load on the node server is 1%, yet when the groups reach about 200 - 500 people, many people experience very high latency. Some people only get the option to vote after 10 seconds or more after voting starts, whereas others get it in a few hundred milisec.

It *seems* to be the case that the people who experience the problem are using the local wifi network, whereas people on their own mobile 3G/4G connection do not.

With the old product, when we did manual polling every second (much more resource intensive) we never had this problem.

does anyone have any experience with many users on the same network using websockets? Why would this happen and/or is this to be expected?

Comment: I wonder if the sudden burst of traffic from sending data to so many endpoints on the same network at the same time is causing the problem. Paradoxically, it may help to space out the transmissions a bit.

Comment: Can your local wifi network even handle 200 - 500 people?

Comment: it's not 'my' local wifi. We do events in many different places, and often the place where the event is hosted has local wifi available. But with the old version - which used http polling every second - never gave such problems at events, so I wonder if its the nature of websocket connections that can make it heavier for wifi routers?